# Symfony Redirect To Search Route If Route Not Found

Tags: php, symfony

I would like users to be able to use `/{keyword}` as a shortcut to `/search/{keyword}` (ideally only if `keyword` doesn't contain a full stop or a slash - i.e. not an obvious attempt to load a page).

I have a [custom 404 page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) but, as this route doesn't have a controller, I don't see how to redirect to the search route without using JavaScript client-side within the content of the `error404.html.twig` and that's terribly bad practice.

The only other solution I can think of would be to have a `/{keyword}` route, somehow prioritising this, and if a route with the path `/$keyword` exists then load that, otherwise redirect to `/search/$keyword` ... but I can't see how to prioritise this route or how to check a route exists by path (I can only see by name).

Can anyone think of a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set lowest priority for this route.

routing.yml:

```
foo:
   path: /foo
   #foo route config

bar:
   path: /bar
   #bar route config       

#other routes
#...

search_alias:
   path: /{keyword}
   defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Redirect:searchKeyword }
   requirements:
       keyword: ^([a-zA_Z0-9\s]+)$
   methods: [GET]
```

`search_alias` will only be called if the routes above it are not matched.

Comment: Fantastic! Sounds daft but I hadn't thought of the reverse side and treating this is a lowest priority route. Elegant & simple, exactly what I was after. Thanks! I've just added the working example to your answer that I'm using to help others who may come here.